# Primefaces - Use an Object in the DefaultScheduleEvent <p:schedule>

Tags: input, primefaces, dialog, schedule

I'm using the `<p:shecule>` and i want to know how can i interact or use this Object data [DefaultScheduleEvent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxI0A.png). 
For example if i want to fill the calendar with more information or save different data than the `String title, Date start, date End`.

Right now i'm filling the calendar using a `for`. And it's working fine. But there are more related information that i want to show in the `<p:dialog>`.
[This is the addition information that i want to save/show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntr9j.png)

```
        for (TimeSheetEntity timeSheetEntity : listaReportesTS) {
        String descripcion = timeSheetEntity.getProyectoE().getDescripcionProyecto();
        Date fechaInicio = obtFechaHora(timeSheetEntity.getDiaLaboral(), timeSheetEntity.getHoraInicio());
        Date fechaFinal = obtFechaHora(timeSheetEntity.getDiaLaboral(), timeSheetEntity.getHoraFin());
        eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(descripcion, fechaInicio, fechaFinal));
    }
```

How can i do it? and how can i save all this data and get the `DefaultScheduleEvent` recognize it?

Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

I created a new class that extends `DefaultScheduleEvent` but still no luck. The event is only saved when i enter the title, the start date and the end date. If i enter any other value nothing happens, not even an error in the console.

public class Prueba extends DefaultScheduleEvent{

```
private AsignacionEntity proyecto;
private TipoActividadEntity actividad;
private boolean horaAlmuerzo;
private String desc;
private String incidente;
private float horasTrabajadas;

public Prueba() {
    super();

}

public Prueba(String title, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    super(title, startDate, endDate);
}
//getters and setters
```

And in the bean:

```
private Prueba pruebaEvento = new Prueba();
```

In the view:

```
 <h:outputText for="incidente" value="IM/ALM"/>
        <p:inputText id="incidente" value="#{registroBean.pruebaEvento.incidente}" required="false" size="5"/>
```

Finally i tried with the `Object data` and set the value from the VO/DTO in the constructor but no luck again.

```
        dse = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
    dse.setData(new TimeSheetVO());
```

Comment: Tried creating your own scheduled event by extending the default one?

Comment: I'm going to try.

Comment: or add `implements ScheduleEvent` to your `TimeSheetEntity`

Comment: I tried  the implements with a new class but is not working, i'm going to try with the Entity and the VO/DTO. Thanks.